# File lost while moving

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had an application deployment file (.war file) on linux(ubuntu 16) in the following folder:
/var/lib/tomcat8/my-webapps/backup/

This backup-folder had the ROOT folder and the ROOT.war file. When i tried to move the ROOT.war file from the back-up folder to its parent folder(my-webapps), it some how got lost somewhere. Following is the command that i used:

```
root@my_server:/var/lib/tomcat8/my-webapps/backup# mv ROOT.war /my-webapps
```

1) Can someone explain what i did there and if i can still recover my file.

2) Also, when i tried to move the whole ROOT folder after this, i got the following error:

```
root@my_server:/var/lib/tomcat8/my-webapps/backup# mv ROOT /my-webapps
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory '/my-webapps' with directory 'ROOT'
```

my-webapps is certainly a directory so i don't understand what the error is trying to say here.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like `/my-webapps` is not a folder, but rather your `ROOT.war` file. Can you add the output of `ls -alh /my-webapps`.

Comment: Give the output of  `ls -lrth /my-webapps`, perhaps you renamed `ROOT.war` to `/my-webapps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial command

```
# mv ROOT.war /my-webapps
```

moved the war file to the root directory and changed its name to `my-webapps`.  To move it to its parent directory, you should have used

```
# mv ROOT.war ../my-webapps
```

In order to recover it, just move my-webapps back where you want it

```
# mv /my-webapps /var/lib/tomcat8/my-webapps/ROOT.war
```

---

As to your comment on your second point, it is true that `/var/lib/tomcat8/my-webapps` is a directory, but `/my-webapps` is a regular file, not a directory; hence the error message when you try to overwrite it with `ROOT`.